# Квадратная картинка на CSS

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как сделать на CSS квадратную картинку? Тоесть имеется несколько картинок, одна 500x100, другая 100x500 обе картинки выводятся параметром `width:30%;` мне нужно сделать их квадратными, `height:30%;` использовать глупо.

Comment: а что Вы уже сделали?

Comment: сама картинка должна быть квадратной в общем aspect ratio должен быть таким а из портретной или из альбомной этого без дефектов не сделать

Comment: Nikolai Shabalin, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть хорошее свойство `aspect-ratio`. Можно задать `aspect-ratio: 1` контейнеру, а самому изображению:

```
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover; //опционально
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style=background-image:url(//via.placeholder.com/400x100.png)></div>
<div style=background-image:url(//via.placeholder.com/300x300.png)></div>
<div style=background-image:url(//via.placeholder.com/100x800.png)></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Один из старых трюков с помощью паддинга "распирать" блок в нужной пропорции. В Вашем случае это 1:1. 
А саму картинку сделать object-fit: cover;

```css
.block {
  
  width: 30%;  
}

.block__inner {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__inner">
    <img src="https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2017/whatisspacet.jpg" class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

вот пример - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQqVXz